# jupyter notebook cant import a file whose path is mentioned in an imported script residing in different directory

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have a directory structure like this:

```
project/ 

       nb/ 
          notebook.ipynb

       python/

             data/file.p
             settings.py
             main.py
```

I am loading `file.p` under settings.py by writing `open("data/file.p","rb")`.

Then I would simply write `from settings import *` in `main.py` and it loads the file. But when I write the same in notebook.ipynb it does not load the file because the current directory changes to `nb/`. Is it possible to load this file in `notebook.ipynb` without changing the directory path inside `settings.py` ?

Answer (score 0):

`Python` is a package and `settings` is a module. So try this.

In notebook.ipynb

```
from python import settings
```

If it is not able to recognize the path, then set `PYTHONPATH` to absolute path of `project` directory and run again.